# primefaces autocomplete event itemSelect listener value null in ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4.2 Autocomplete.

In ManagedBean when I select a row as I type characters in autocomplete, I am not able to get the value in method `handleSelect(SelectEvent event)` {

What could be the reason for this? Ideally I would like to fill or populate other columns in jsf page when I select a row from autocomplete values.

JSF code for autocomplete

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{empMB.selectedEmployee}"
                            id="basicPojo" minQueryLength="3" 
                            completeMethod="#{myMB.complete}" var="p"
                            itemLabel="#{p.empName}" 
                             converter="#{employeeNameConverter}"
                            forceSelection="true" >                           
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
                            listener="#{myMB.handleSelect}" />
```

ManagedBean method

```
public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {
String value = (String) event.getObject();
System.out.println("selected "+value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you didn't provide `itemValue` attribute in `p:autoComplete` component.

Comment: Partlov In primefaces [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteSelect.jsf), there is no itemValue attribute defined.

Comment: Besides for itemValue attribute converter is a must?

Comment: Partlov yes you are right, I added as `itemValue="#{p.empName}"` and I was able to get selected value in ManagedBean

Comment: Of corse it is defined `itemValue="#{player}"`, in first example value is just string, not a POJO. If you can define value with some basic type from your POJO field (some String, Integer...) converter is unnecessary.