# Primefaces autoComplete wouldn't clean it's output

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a dialog with two radioButtons, one of them connected to drop-down list and another to autoComplete. When autocomplete completes my input and than I switch to second radio button - input I gave to autocomplete is still rendered in the field, despite listener I added that cleans the value which linked to the autoComplete.

For example: I search in autoComplete "ant", it completes to "Anton", than I click on second radio button, autoComplete becomes disabled and it's text sets itself to "ant" again.

- I've tried in listener to set value to "" and null
- I've tried to add itemValue to autocomplete, as stated in [primefaces autocomplete event itemSelect listener value null in ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746429/primefaces-autocomplete-event-itemselect-listener-value-null-in-managedbean)
- I've tried to add resetInput, but radio button is not an ActionSource
- I've tried to add to ajax onfocus method that will call something like ":form1:autoComplete.value =''", but no avail (and javascript is not my strong side)

xhtml:

```xml
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{bean.selectCopyType}" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select person to put item on:" itemValue="Person" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Add item to the pool:" itemValue="Pool" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.onSelectButton}" event="valueChange" 
            update=":form1:person_input_text :form1:pool_select" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<h:panelGrid columns="3" id="radioPanel">
    <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" 
                   process=":form1:person_input_text :form1:pool_select" 
                   update=":form1:person_input_text :form1:pool_select" />
    <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="Select person to put item on:" />
    <p:autoComplete id="person_input_text" minQueryLength="0" forceSelection="true" 
                    emptyMessage="No result found" value="#{bean.newCurrentOwner}" 
                    effect="blind" completeMethod="#{bean.complete}" 
                    disabled="#{bean.selectCopyType == 'Pool'}" 
                    itemValue="#{bean.newCurrentOwner}" widgetVar="person_input_text">
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" 
                   process=":form1:person_input_text :form1:pool_select"
                   update=":form1:person_input_text :form1:pool_select">
    </p:radioButton>
    <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Add item to the pool:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectOneMenu" id="pool_select" value="#{bean.pool_select}" 
                     disabled="#{bean.selectCopyType == 'Person'}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.pools}" id="selectPool" />
        <p:ajax update=":form1:person_input_text" listener="#{bean.onSelectPool}" 
                onfocus="person_input_text.value='' " />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

onSelectPool code:

```java
public void onSelectPool() {
    this.setNewCurrentOwner(null);
}
```

I use Java ee 6, primefaces 5.0 (tried also with 5.1 - same result)

Can be reproduced with following: [code](http://pastebin.com/5eQgtEhj)  [xhtml](http://pastebin.com/yiq1y5nb).

Comment: Are you using CDI beans and if yes what Scope are they in? You have to remeber that the value is also stored in the JSF component tree, if the bean is not available any more then the old value will be rendered back. Also the actual xhtml and java code would help.

Comment: Bean is ViewScoped, non-CDI, updating answer with the code

Comment: I am not 100% certain but I think you should only define the id defined in xhtml in the update and not :form1:person_input_text. Also have you checked that bean.newCurrentOwner is called when update is preformed? You should also check the server response with Browser debug tools...

Comment: It's enclosed in larger form, so form1: is valid path to element.

Comment: Please check what you get as partial render response from the server, if the component is not part of the partial response something is wrong with the specified update id (I am still not convinced that that is the proper way to do it since you referencing an xhtml id within the same scope). If it returns the same out of date value, you will have to check that the listner really resets the value and that the getter is called, otherwise the outdated value from the JSF component tree will be returned.

Comment: I just noticed that you are missing the event in the p:ajax it may be irrelevant since it states in the documentation that it is inherited from the attached component, still try specifying the event="change"

Comment: Oh and also your onfocus can not work, since you put it on the p:ajax, you would have to put that on the actual input component p:selectOneMenu.

Comment: After removing invalid/illegal attributes, I can't reproduce the *"text sets itself to "ant" again"* part based on the code and information posted so far.

Comment: Came back to work, @dngfng - tried your tips - not succeeded.

Comment: @BalusC - here's the video of the "itself" part : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx4u0zazc3fr7i3/test.avi?dl=0

Comment: @dngfng I tried to get a response from the server - I'm getting some encrypted viewstate information and PF method I use to show the form.

Comment: A video doesn't help us in reproducing the problem. Post a MCVE.

Comment: That means that the component is not rendered for the response. Try changing the id in your update statement.

Comment: @BalusC MCVE: code http://pastebin.com/5eQgtEhj xhtml: http://pastebin.com/yiq1y5nb

Comment: @dngfng I tried - that same, see previous comment. I succeeded to fix it by javasript setting element value to '', but I don't think it's right solution. Also upgraded by the way Primefaces to 5.1

Comment: @Anton, it's preferable to update your question with additional data such as MCVE code, not to post it in 3rd side services and providing a link. Just from my experience people doesn't like to go back and forth.